# Let $f$ be differentiable on $\Bbb R$ with $1\le f'(x)\le2 \forall x \in \Bbb R$ and $f(0)=0$. Show that $x\le f(x)\le2x \;\;\;\forall x\ge0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I really don't know how to start. But I quite not sure can i use MVT for proving this problem. In the point, i don't know how to suppose f(x) could u pls help ToT

Answer (score 2):

Apply mean value theorem to the two points $x\not =0$ and $0$ to see that $$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(c)$$ for some suitable $c$. While $1\le f'(c)\le 2$, we have $1\le \frac{f(x)}{x}\le 2$. For $x=0$, the result is obvious.